# How to addClass to an element that appears later in the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jquery code:

```
$('.kv-editable-reset').addClass('green');
```

which should add the class 'green' to this element:

```
<button type="button" class="btn kv-editable-reset"></button>
```

but it does not work because .kv-editable-reset appears only later in the page, after click on the following button:

```
<button type="button" class="kv-editable-link"></button>
```

How can I detect elements that appears in the page only **after** another element has been clicked?

Comment: You could use a MutationObserver, but that's really a last resort. Do you have control over when the `kv-editable-reset` class is added to the element? Or is an event raised when it happens? If so, place your logic there.

Comment: you could use `.delay(1000)` for 1sec delay on your function

Comment: @Matt.S what happens if the class is added 20 seconds later? Or if the class is added after 0.001s yet you make the user wait 1sec :)

Comment: @OP Assuming this is for UI purposes only, then you could just put the CSS rules for `green` in to the .kv-editable-reset` class

Comment: @aliengirl you mean `.kv-editable-reset` is dynamic button which appears after click of `.kv-editable-link`

Comment: `delay()` only works on queued items. You can not use it to delay `addClass()` (unless you create your own queue).

Answer (score 0):

Just listen to the click event for that button and then readdress adding the `.green` class.

By using `.toggleClass('green', true)` you don't even have to care about picking up pre-existing buttons and re-assign this class to them

```js
$(() => {
  $('.kv-editable-link').on('click', function() {
    $("html").append(`<button type="button" class="btn kv-editable-reset">kv-editable-reset</button>`);
    $('.kv-editable-reset').toggleClass('green', true);
  });
});
```

```css
.green{
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="kv-editable-link">kv-editable-link</button>
```

Comment: If you read question exactly OP want to *detect elements that appears in the page*

Comment: @Mohammad I understand that he *wants* to, but the OP doesn't necessarily *need* to.

Comment: If they don't control when the content is added, they do

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan valid.